# attributeBindings in a View aren't updating based on model change

Tags: ember.js

I wonder if I'm just doing something fundamentally wrong here but I'm trying to have a model define the style attribute in a view. So for example the ember view uses the card template and starts out with `<div style="color: green">...</div>` that is backed by the model property color. When I change it somewhere else via `App.Card.find(2).set("color", "color: red").save()` I expect the template to update the value, but it does nothing. Using `{{ bindAttr style model.color }}` in the template directly does keep the value in sync, but then I have an extra ember-view div element.

http://jsfiddle.net/dbhWg/3/

javascript:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.Router.map(function () {
    // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return App.Card.find()
    }
});

App.Card = DS.Model.extend({
    color: DS.attr('string'),
});

App.Card.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1,
    color: "color: green"
}, {
    id: 2,
    color: "color: blue"
}];

App.CardView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "card",
    attributeBindings: ['style'],
    style: function () {
        return this.get('controller.model.color')
    }.property('controller.model'),
    didInsertElement: function () {
        App.Card.find(2).set('color', "color: red").save()
        console.log(App.Card.find(2).get('color'))
    }
});
```

templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="card">
    <h1> HELLO THERE </h1>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2> Welcome to Ember.js </h2>
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{#each item in model}} 
      {{render "card" item}} 
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't seem to match your example

Comment: Whoops sorry, forked it off someone else's fiddle, corrected the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You forgot to add the dependecency for the color in computed property**

```
style: function () {
    return this.get('controller.model.color')
}.property('controller.model.color'),
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Unspecified/dbhWg/5/)

<strike>As far as I know, you can't update CSS using `bindAttr` what</strike> I'd suggest you to use class instead, define classes as follows:

```
.red{
  color: red;
}

.green{
  color: green;
}

.blue: {
  color: blue;
}
```

The update fixtures as:

```
App.Card.FIXTURES = [{
  id: 1,
  color: "green"  
}, {
  id: 2,
  color: "blue"
}];
```

Bind the color to `class` as follows

```
App.CardView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "card",
    classNameBindings: ['color'],
    color: function () {
        return this.get('controller.model.color');
    }.property('controller.model.color'),
    didInsertElement: function () {
        App.Card.find(2).set('color', "red").save();
        console.log(App.Card.find(2).get('color'));
    }
});
```

Comment: I simplified with color so that it was easier. In the real thing I was trying to set position. So the actual property was a string like "left: 100px; top: 100px;". So the css class change doesn't really work.

As I noted <div {{bindAttr style model.position }}> </div> works though. Guess it's surprising when the view version doesn't, especially since class changes as you noted do work. If enough people agree that this is a little inconsistent I'll investigate a pull request.

Comment: you want to add or subtract pixels from the current position ?

Comment: Yes or in other cases arbitrarily set the position to move the element around, think of it as draggable or something.

Comment: See the updated answer you forgot to add dependency for the color property, will that solve your problem ?

Comment: I swear I thought I tried a variant of this, but YES your answer does work! Thanks.